# DataSheet views in Sharepoint 2007 don't work with Office 2010 beta installed

Tags: microsoft-office, office-2010-beta, sharepoint-2007

Is anyone aware of a workaround to allow IE to display Datasheet views for lists in Sharepoint 2007 when you have Office 2010 beta installed?

I understand that SP uses Excel to display datasheet views, but it's surprising that you can't get the ActiveX download that makes them work when you don't have office.

Any ideas on how to get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this exact same problem. I found these instructions http://www.sharepointtalk.info/2010/06/sharepoint-datasheet-view-and-office.html and found that reinstalling SharePoint Designer 2007 corrected the problem. Make sure you include the  Windows SharePoint Services component.